# If within __main I call BEQ some_func, can I call bx lr at the end of some_func to return to the next instruction in main?

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

If within __main I call BEQ some_func, can I call bx lr at the end of some_func to return to the next instruction in main?

I have done this successfully with BL / bx lr, but not sure if it can be implemented similarly with BEQ / bx lr.

Ex 1:
If I implement the logic below, BL saves the instruction after init to LR and branches to init. When bx lr is called at the end of init, it returns to the next instruction in main (LDR r0, =0x40000000).

```
init        PROC
            ....
            bx  lr
            ENDP

            ENTRY
__main      PROC
            BL  init
            LDR r0, =0x40000000
            ...
            ENDP
            END
```

Ex 2:
Below is the logic I am trying to implement. I'm wondering if it works, and if not, how I can implement something similar.

```
up          PROC
            ...
            bx lr ; will this branch back to execute next instr. "BL delay"?
            ENDP

            ENTRY
__main      PROC

loop        ...
            TST r4, 0x08
            BEQ up ; is LR automatically saved?
            BL delay
            B loop
```

Comment: Use instruction reference guide to verify what each instruction does (and if there some other exists), but `beq` does not update `lr`. So your second example needs more code to create the branching within main, then one of the branches will do `bl up` and jump back into the other branch with delay loop. For fun: x86 has unconditional `call` too, conditional jumps don't update return address. But Zilog Z80 had few `call condition,subroutine` instructions (together with those common conditional jumps). I'm actually too lazy to check ARM instruction set, but as it's RISC-like, don't expect "beql"

Comment: @Ped7g: ARM32 in ARM mode (not thumb) has predicated execution for *everything*, using the high 4 bits of the instruction word.  (There are a few cases where it's not supported, i.e. the result is undefined by the ISA, though.  I forget if that's only for predicated execution of NEON instructions, or if that applies to any non-SIMD/FP instructions.  Like you, too lazy to check the ISA ref.)  In Thumb2, there's an `it`/`ite`/ (if-then/if-then-else) instruction that predicates the next 1-3 instructions on a condition.  Logically equivalent to branching, but executes differently.

Comment: @PeterCordes now you mention it... (and I actually *did* few kilobytes of ARM code around 2001 for GameBoy Advance, IIRC ARM7TDMI (ARMv4)) ... yeah, I think there's some conditioning in every full word instruction. Still, no point to check myself, the OP will need to learn how to use ISA docs, as he clearly does not, and that's impossible to code in assembly without constantly checking the details of instructions.

Comment: "beq does not update lr" - Ped7g

That was all I needed. I read the documentation already, it didn't make sense to me, which is why I came here. No need to spit on people who are learning something for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

`beq` never modifies `lr`.  It's just a conditionally-executed `b` instruction.

A `b` or `beq` to another function would be a tail-call that returns to main's caller (unless you manually set `lr` to a new return address).  Look at optimized compiler output for `int foo(int a) { return bar(a+3); }`.

The CPU doesn't treat `beq` differently based on the target address.  The CPU doesn't even know that it's jumping outside the current "function". 
 The CPU doesn't really even know about functions, although it might have a call/return branch predictor that predicts branch targets for `bx lr` instructions.

IDK if predicated execution works for branch-and-link, but if so you could `BLEQ`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand this explanation. My question is, if within main a function is branched to with the statement BEQ, and then at the end of that function bx lr is called, will the function return to the next statement in main?

Comment: BL can be conditional in ARMv7, but is unpredictable in an IT block unless at the end (i.e. you can't return into the IT block).